# Compiler switch to disable const_cast semantics in c-style casts?

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-options, const-cast

Recently I stumbled over code such as this:

```
void foo(const Bar* b) {
  ...
  takes_nonconst_param_fn((Bar*)b);
  ...
```

Obviously, the developer didn't know what he was doing, but if the compiler hadn't silently accepted the c-style-cast and at least required a proper `const_cast`, he may have though twice before committing this.

So this got me thinking, do any modern compilers have a switch to prevent `const_cast`semantics for c-style-casts?

It's simply not practical to prevent all occurrences of c-style-casts and it's a necessary evil to allow their `static_` and `reinterpret_` semantics (if only for some library code), but my impression is, that legitimate usage of c-style-casts to cast away constness is very rare in **C++** code bases, so maybe it should be possible to disable it altogether?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you declare foo as 'void foo(const Bar* b) const'?

Comment: @James: why do you expect that to affect how explicit casts work? If `foo` is a member function, then that would make the object members `const` within the function; if not, then that would be an error.

Comment: Actually I wish I could disable all but their `static_cast` form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC has the option `-Wcast-qual` to warn when a C-style cast removes a type qualifier. Combined with `-Werror`, you can prevent it completely if you want.

Comment: Also consider -Wold-style-cast for all old casts.

Comment: Nice: Another flag I need to add to my list of needed flags.